# Favicon and Image render on Iphone

Tags: iphone, safari, render, show, favicon

I have this next code, but I cant make the icon show nor the image on the iphone render. How could I fix this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="contruccion">
            <img id="Construccion" width="801" height="601" name="Construccion" alt="propiedad de CharLi Guatemala" src="images/siteCon.png"></img>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no trace of your icon in the code. Although this is not necessarily an error, could you describe what you did about it? And about the image: what happens in another browser? Is the issue specific to iOS? On iOS, how do you try to display your page? With a classic browser such as Safari, on in a kind of "web view" within an iOS app?

Comment: Yes it shows in any other browser on a computer or on the iphone,   it does show in safari on a mac computer, but not in the safari browser on the iPhone.

Comment: I will post again my code were it does have the icon code

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>CharLi Guatemala</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/charLi.ico">
<style type="text/css">
#contruccion {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 40px;
 height: 600px;
 width: 800px;
}
body {
 background-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS does not support the `favicon.ico` file. You should [create a touch icon, as defined by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

The easiest way to get the job done is to create a 152x152 picture named `apple-touch-icon.png` and placed at the root of your web site. The iOS devices will find it and use it in bookmarks and for link on homepage.

You can also use this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) to create all iOS pictures and HTML declarations at once. Full disclosure: I am the author of this site.